# Exponential operator in C++ loop

Tags: c++, matlab

I wrote C++ codes and matlab codes to test speed. My C++ code is:

```
int nrow = dim[0], ncol = dim[1];
double tmp, ldot;

for (int k = ncol - 1; k >= 0; --k){
    grad[k] = 0;
    for (int j = nrow - 1; j >= 0; --j){
        tmp = exp(eta[j + nrow * k]);
        ldot = (-Z[j + nrow * k] + tmp / (1 + tmp));
        grad[k] += A[j] * ldot;
    }
}
```

My matlab code is:

```
prob = exp(eta);
prob = prob./(1+prob);
ldot = prob - Z;
grad=sum(repmat(A,1,nGWAS).*ldot);
```

I run each code 100 times, it took over 5 seconds for C++ and only 1.2 seconds for matlab.

Anyone can help my here? Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations?

Comment: You should clarify your question (maybe the title). It seems you are asking why the C++ code is slower or how the C++ code could be made faster.

Comment: how big is your data?

Comment: nrow = 50000, ncol = 10. Yes, I compiled it using mex in matlab using visual studio 12.0 compiler.

Comment: what are the types of `eta`, `Z`, `A`, `grad`?  C++ arrays?  Vectors?...

Comment: yes, they are all c++ 1-dim arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The folks at matlab know very well how to optimize matrix access.

You chose to access it column by column.  My initial guess is that the matrix is laid out in memory row by row.  This causes your code to run over the whole matrix `ncol` times.  Cache misses all over the place.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But in my understanding, matlab mex pass all matrix in column manner. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @JinLiu are you saying that you are doing a mex on the c++ code? This was written nowhere in your question. Further, arrays in c++ is not the type used by matlab, which uses the `mxArray`. Further, as far as I know c and c++ arrays are row major. This comes from the definition of the array. A two dimensional array `arry[2][3]` is acctually a 2 element long array of 3 element long arrays.

Comment: @JinLiu Arrays in c++ is not the type used by matlab, which uses the mxArray. Further, as far as I know c and c++ arrays are row major. This comes from the definition of the array. A two dimensional array `arry[2][3]` is acctually an array of 2 elements each containing a 3 element long array. A 2 dimensional array is in other words an array of arrays.

Comment: @patrik on second sight, OP is accessing the arrays continuously from `nrows*ncols - 1` down to `0`.  Downwards.

Comment: @patrik actually, I used 1-dimensional array (vectorized matrix by column). This should not be the reason for slow speed.

Comment: Are you compiling the C code in Debug or Release mode? this makes some difference

Comment: @MinaKamel I used mex to compile and run this code and record the running time to C++ code pasted.

Comment: @MinaKamel Could you paste the running time here?